# Dar color a texto con CSS

Tags: css

A ver si alguien me ayuda, porque es algo que he probado ya de 1000 formas y no consigo hacer.
En una archivo PHP genero una tabla con el siguiente código:

```
require("../Includes/formatodatos.php");

echo "<link href='estilo.css' rel='stylesheet type='text/css' float='left'/>";
        echo "    
            <tr>        
                <td>$NumeroID</br></td>        
                <td>$Nombre</br></td>
                <td>$Apellidos</br></td>
                <td>$Cantidad</br></td>         
            </tr>";
```

En el archivo "formatodatos.php" lo que hago es añadir formato al campo "Cantidad" para que lo muestre como yo deseo. Pero lo que no consigo llevar a cabo es que si $Cantidad es mayor que un valor lo ponga en un determinado color, por ejemplo, rojo.

```
if (!empty($Cantidad)){
        $Cantidad = number_format($Cantidad,0,",",".") ." Kg";
    } 
    else{
        $Cantidad = "-----";
    }
```

Comment: Hola Sergio, en el código que compartis no se ve nada donde analises el valor de cantidad como así tampoco como darle color. Sería bueno que presiones [edit] y agregues al menos 1 de las 1000 de las formas que has intentado (_no importa que no funcione_)

Comment: Tu código no corresponde con el titulo del post. No veo donde intentes dar color con CSS

Answer (score 1):

Antes que nada, primero te recomiendo que si tu estructura predominante en tu archivo .php es HTML, evites utilizar `echo "";` para imprimirlo. Es decir, deja todo normal en HTML y cuando vayas a utilizar PHP lo incrustes y no viceversa, sino te vas a confundir más. Algo así:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Tu index.php</title>
    <link href='estilo.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
</head>
<body>

    <?php require("../Includes/formatodatos.php"); ?>

    <table>
        <tr>        
            <td><?php echo $NumeroID;?></td>        
            <td><?php echo $Nombre;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $Apellidos;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $Cantidad;?></td>         
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Segundo, tu problema de estilos puede ser algo tan evidente y por eso nunca ves cambios a pesar de las 1000 formas que has intentado, ya que tienes una sintaxis incorrecta en tu referencia con CSS, ya que estás cerrando mal las comillas y que el atributo `float` no existe en la etiqueta `link`. [Ver estructura y atributos que acepta `<link>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp). E incluso hasta este punto no sé si hayas puesto el `<link>` dentro del `<head></head>` como debe ser.

Entonces lo que deberías cambiar

```
<link href='estilo.css' rel='stylesheet type='text/css' float='left'/>
```

a

```
<link href='estilo.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
```

Quizá no te habías dado cuenta porque en algunos editores al imprimirlo con `echo` y dejarlo entre comillas dobles ya no te marca la sintaxis del HTML y es más fácil que te confundas con las aperturas y cierres. Por eso te sugería al principio usar HTML y que lo incrustado sea PHP.

Entiendo que quieres cambiar el color según lo que imprime la variable `$Cantidad`. Esto sería fácil hacerlo con algo de JavaScript, pero suponiendo que sólo quieres usar PHP, entonces en tu archivo `formatodatos.php` puedes añadir la siguiente condicional:

```
//Aquí pones la condición que necesites.

if($Cantidad > 1000){
    //asignas una variable que contenga la declaración en CSS
    $estilo_cantidad="color:blue;";
} else { 
    $estilo_cantidad="color:red;";
}
```

y simplemente le agregas la variable nueva con un `style` a tu `<td>`

```
<td style="<?php echo $estilo_cantidad; ?>"><?php echo $Cantidad;?></br></td>
```

Con esto ya cambiaría el estilo de tu `<td>` donde está tu variable `$Cantidad` según su valor y las condiciones que definiste.

Ahora bien, si lo quieres dejar en tu formato de que imprimas el HTML con PHP, entonces sería así:

```
<?php
echo "    
       <tr>        
           <td>".$NumeroID."</br></td>        
           <td>".$Nombre."</br></td>
           <td>".$Apellidos."</br></td>
           <td style='".$estilo_cantidad."'>".$Cantidad."</br></td>         
       </tr>";
?>
```

También podrías jugar con estas variables y condicionales para que en lugar de que se muestre en el `style` se muestre como una `clase` (y para ello ya deberías tener creadas las clases en tu `estilo.css)`